# Standard Deviation c++ Formula advice

Tags: c++, linux, windows, math, computer-science

I have this assignment in which i will show the prompt for it:

Write a program that reads in a set of test score data from the user. (Test
scores should be entered in decimal form to represent the percentage grade). Once the user has
finished entering the test scores (entering -1 will signal the end of input), print out the number of
tests entered, the average of the tests, and the standard deviation. Use the following formula
(Welford’s method) to calculate the standard deviation:
[(Standard Deviaton Formula)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1T2j.png)

You can compute this quantity by keeping track of the count (number of tests), the sum, and the sum
of squares as you process the input values.
Note: Although there are other ways to calculate the standard deviation, please use this method. This
method is used since it only requires one pass of the data. Do not use arrays or vectors.

Now the code below is what I have so far. In the terminal, I'm getting wrong numbers for the average and Std. Deviation outputs [(Terminal Output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seu1A.png). Is there anything wrong with my math? Any help is appreciated. EDIT: Here is the data I'm using and the expected results I should be getting:

```
 1.  67.8
 2.  95.6
 3.  89.5
 4.  76.7
 5.  71.3
 6.  83.2
 7.  90.6
 8.  56.1
 9.  98.6
 10. 85.2
```

result:

```
Number of Test Scores: 10
Average : 81.46
Std. Deviation: 13.39
```

Code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    double sum = 0;
    double sumSq = 0;
    double grade = 0;
    int numtests = 0;

    cout << "Enter the test scores. Once finished, enter -1 to end input.\n";
    cin >> grade;

    while (grade != -1)
    {
        cin >> grade;
        sum = sum + grade;
        sumSq = sumSq + pow(grade, 2);
        numtests++;
    }

    double average = (sum / numtests);
    double std = (sumSq - numtests * pow(average, 2) / (numtests - 1));

    cout << "The number of scores: " << numtests << "\n";
    cout << "Average: " << average << "\n";
    cout << "Std. Deviation: " << std << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post image links. Simply copy the text and paste into the question.

Comment: Sample data, expected numbers and what you're getting would be useful.

Comment: @Shawn I added the data im using and the answers I should be getting into the post

Comment: Is there any benefit for using `pow(grade, 2)` instead of just using `grade*grade`?

Answer (score 4):

You've written the function so "-1" is part of the calculation which isn't what you want.  I could fix it for you, but I think you can take it from that hint.  And now that I look again, the first number is NOT part of your calculation.

Comment: Just as a suggestion, a debugger would have thrown both issues up into your face almost immediately.  Given you have the tag "windows" I assume you are using DevStudio.  It has an excellent debugger . . . make it your friend.